# Does the word "buttress," which is both a noun & verb, follow the rules about where to put emphasis based on its part of speech?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, vocabulary, emphasis, stress

> buttress (n.) any prop or support
>
> buttress (v.) to support by a buttress; prop up

Words like *combat, abstract, project, and convict* change the syllable that's stressed based on whether you're using their noun or verb or adjective form. I thought the word *buttress,* which has both noun and verb forms, should also follow the rule like the others do, but I can't seem to find anything that differentiates its pronunciation based on its part of speech. Does anyone know if it follows this [initial-stress-derived noun rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun)? I know it's not much of an established rule and *buttress* could be an outlier but I'm just not sure.

Comment: Most dictionaries provide syllable stress guidance.  What does the dictionary tell you?

Comment: It says that it's stressed on the first syllable and thats it; it doesn't say anything about noun or verb form pronunciation.

Comment: Great.  Now look at another noun/verb on your list (like convict) and see what it says.  Then draw a conclusion. (The pronunciation doesn't change...)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a [dictionary will tell you](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it does not follow the rule, but the "rule" is only a rule of thumb, like the vast majority of "rules" when it comes to natural languages. There are numerous cases where the stress is always on the first syllable like *number* or *quarry*, and others where the accent is always on the second like *command* or *effect*, and others where it depends on the dialect, like *reply* or *police*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an observant question!

The initial-stress-derived noun rule you reference is just a convention.

Buttress isn't one of the words where it typically applies, i.e. it's commonly pronounced with similar emphasis in its noun and verb forms.

There are many words where this occurs: *refrain* and *accord* are two examples.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you see is by no means a rule for English pronunciation.  For instance, the word "exit" is pronounced the same whether it is used as a verb or noun.  Most of the words that do follow the convention have a pattern of a prefix and a root in their construction: conduct, combat, direct, project, attribute, increase, etc.  Again, not a rule, but certainly a better indicator for words that might follow this stress-changing convention.